# Qt Creator error when include boost C++ header

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I am new to Qt.
I have a simple Widget application, and I try to link to boost C++,
My boost lib was built with MSVC all libboost files has "msvc-140/141" names
I add the include path and lib path as shown in the graph below
[image: my pro file]
then I go to my header file of the mainwindow and include the boost thread and signals headers, then the Qt creator pop up an warning:
"The code model could not parse an included file, which might...."
But strange thing happens from here
after I added the include files and turn back to source file
I found [image: mainwindow.cpp]
I have never encountered this issue and I couldn't find solutions online.
Is this due to the dynamic linking problem with boost C++?
(I need boost because some of external dlls use boost signals/slots mechanism and I encountered the same issue when trying link with them. So I decided to make things simple to check if the link with boost fails in Qt)
Does anyone encounter this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get better responses for your problem.

Comment: In particular, it is expected that you post your code as text (not as image).

Comment: You should add `INCLUDEPATH += YOUR_BOOST_PATH` into your .pro file.

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem by switching off the CLang code model and amend the C++11 -> C++ 14 in my project file I will follow the rules next time. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by switching off the CLang code model and amend the C++11 -> C++ 14 in my project file

Charles Dec 20 '18 at 10:18

Comment: I appreciate your effort to make an answer for this from OPs comment. But please restrict to the answering part.

Comment: I just cited the guy above, to make clear  how he solved it. So other users have it easier to see the direct answer!
Not everybody is looking through the comments. 
Downvote is very uncool for this, in my opinion.

Comment: Downvote is not by me. When I "appreciate" I do not downvote.